# Angular can't read property data of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm having an issue with calling my data from a json file.  When I click a button to have it appear in a textarea, it does nothing for the first click, but works like expected after that.  What the program does is gets an id from dashboard and based on that id grabs different json file to pull in. 
The program shows an error of:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at StepService.webpackJsonp.102.StepService.populateList (step.service.ts:69)
    at CalibrationDetailComponent.webpackJsonp.101.CalibrationDetailComponent.next

step.service.ts

```
private jsonData: any; //Json data
public list: String[] = []; //Holds the list of steps
public listLength: number; //Length of the list
public listCurrent: number = 0; //Current step the list is on

//Gets the json file
  public getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }

  //Subscribe
  public subScribe2Json() {
    this.getJson().subscribe(data => (this.jsonData = data));
  }

  //Populates the list from the json so I can pull out specific steps
  public populateList() {
    this.jsonData.data.forEach(element => { //The line that throws the error
      this.list.push(element.name);
    });
    this.listLength = this.list.length;
  }

  //Returns the mainStepText with the current step
  public getJsonData(): String {
    this.mainStepText = this.list[this.listCurrent];
    return this.mainStepText;
  }
```

calibration-detail.component.ts

next button method

```
next() { //Advances step
    this.stepService.subScribe2Json();
    if (this.stepService.listCurrent < 1) { //Makes sure only runs once to populate the list
      this.stepService.populateList(); //Populates list from the json array
     }
    if (this.stepService.listCurrent < this.stepService.listLength) { //make sure dont go past number of steps
        this.stepService.subScribe2Json(); //Sub to list
        this.mainStepText = this.stepService.getJsonData(); //Grab the data from the list and output to main textarea
        this.stepService.listCurrent ++; //Increments the step
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You can't expect jsonData to be defined immediately after you've sent the HTTP request. It will only be defined much later, when the HTTP response comes back. Subscribe from your component, not from the service. And use the jsonData in the subscribe callback.

Comment: I have tried that but it throws: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at StepService.webpackJsonp.102.StepService.populateList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but an answer to what the problem is. And direct your thought into the right direction depending on what you want to achieve.

You call

```
this.stepService.subScribe2Json();
if (this.stepService.listCurrent < 1) {
...
```

this calls the first method and immediately the second without waiting for the data. And then of course it fails because it is not there yet.

Depending on your use case you could either return the Observable (maybe change it to a Promise,... not 100% sure) and then:

```
return this.getJson().subscribe(data => (this.jsonData = data));
```

and something like

```
this.stepService.subScribe2Json().then(/* do all stuff here */);
```

or initialize

```
private jsonData: any = [];
```

but here of course you don't have anything on the first run.

Comment: Even if initialize jsonData it then throws the error: 
"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: Thats because you want to loop over `this.jsonData.data` and not `this.jsonData'. In order to to that you could initialize via `private jsonData: any = {data: []};`